# How to call a Asynchronous SOAP web service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, ios9

I want to execute my SOAP web service Asynchronously,Because I got some lag in getting data while calling synchronously.Also i was able to get result when calling a single web service when a multiple web service is called in (view did load) or in (view will appear) i was unable to get the data.

Can anyone tell how to call a asynchronous SOAP webService: Here is my code

```
cws = [[CustomWebService alloc]init];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my soap string"];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(msgCount) name:@"my response name" object:nil];
    NSDictionary *Details=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];
    [cws getSoapAction:@".........." andNameSpace:@"" andDetails:Details andUrlIs:[AppDelegate URLSource] andSoapMessage:soapMessage ];
    [cws getPageName:@"my response name"];
    NSLog(@"SOAP MESSAGE IS  %@",soapMessage);
```

And I get the response here:

```
-(void)msgCount
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
NSMutableDictionary *diict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[cws msgCount]];
NSLog(@"the response is %@",diict);

}
```

Comment: u can use afnetwork or asihttp or nsurlrequest

Comment: vaibby Tanks i will try.

Comment: which 1 u r gona try?

Comment: i fell complex  is their any simple smart way to solve this.

Comment: try using nsurlrequest for starter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103571/discussion-between-arun-and-vaibby).

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your webservice call in a GCD async block to make the code run asynchronously in the background

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //code that should run asynchronously
});
```

Comment: which code i want to wrap here 1. soapStringMethod or 2.my response method -(void)msgCount

Comment: your soap string method, can just put all your code in the block and should work

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"UR URL"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = @"UR KEY1=UR VALUE1";    //for single variable

 //OR for Multiple 

[request setValue:@"UR VALUE1" forKey:@"UR KEY1"];
[request setValue:@"UR VALUE2" forKey:@"UR KEY2"];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
     if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
                    } 
}];
```